# How to perform element's inspector effect over elements without modifying css

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm going to build an extension for google chrome that needs to kind of act like an inspector, altought it's not going to have all its features. Let's take firebug lite as example, it makes elements be in evidence, kind of overriding it with a light blue layer, but it doesn't look like firebug has changed its style. I'd pretty much like to do something like that, but haven't find anything yet.

Anyone could guess how it works?!

That's what my app is supposed to do:

[image]

Comment: It's a duplicate.

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829804/highlight-node-with-chrome-devtools-extension

It helped me a lot.

Comment: Well, the answer there says "add a style", which is not exactly what you ask for..

Comment: Please remove the google-chrome-app tag.