# Call "Select an element" from a sidebar button

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a Google Chrome Extension for UI Web Testing. And I need to call the native Chrome selector of elements, which You can invoke by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or via the toolbar:

[image: Select an element: icon]

But I want to call it after click on my button which located in the elements sidebar:

[image: sidebar button (the aim)]

How can  I do that from a javascript click event of a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to invoke the built-in element selector from within the extension. Well, except the weird method of writing a separately installable native OS application that communicates with your extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API and sends a click event to the toolbar or triggers the hotkey.

A workable solution though is to use a 3rd-party JavaScript library that imitates the element selector behavior and once the element is selected you can [highlight it in the Elements panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829804/highlight-node-with-chrome-devtools-extension).

Comment: **Thanks!** I think the most simple solution is using events for any elements. I can intercept a click event and get a title or an innerText in order to paste it in the field with the aim button. And I just will stop propagation of the event after it.