# Chrome Extension - Devtools - invoke element selector programatically

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to invoke the "Element selector" to be invoked from dev-tools js or background js. I checked the chrome api documentation and could not find a direct .

[image: Chrome Inspector window]

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829804/highlight-node-with-chrome-devtools-extension) solution. It is launching an inspect session with the supplied argument ex.

```js
inspect(document.body)
```

I want to allow user select the element. I want to reuse the element selection facility given by devtools inspect element

Could you please point me to an api or any set of statements by which I can achieve the same?

Comment: I too, would like to do this :'(